# How to unzip(extract) 7zip(.7z ext) files in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, zip, 7zip

I'm working on jenkins pipeline.
I managed to unzip .zip files using jenkins utility steps plugin.
However, a few files are zipped by 7zip which produces .7z files and they are not recognized by the plugin.
It outputs an error with "END of zip file header not recognized".

My approach was to write cmd command in pipeline to unzip .7z but for some reason it's not working.

Some alternatives could be

1. somehow customize the utility plugin to unzip .7z
2. fix cmd commands to unzip
3. Any other ideas or solutions would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you share your attempt to unzip it?

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 would be the most straightforward solution. Other than that you can consider using a Groovy script to do the extraction.